# Rendering string as razor cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("ViewName");  // cshtml file name
}
```

That is normally works.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string razor = "<p>Date: @DateTime.Now</p>";
    return View(razor);
}
```

Can I do something like that? Not render a .cshtml file, render a string...

-- Edit------

I actually create .cshtml files programmatically. For example i gonna use @Html.TextBoxFor(...) or foreach statement in my string. – E-D just now edit

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question:

Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HtmlString razor = new HtmlString(string.Format("<p>Date: {0}</p>", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    return View(razor);
}
```

View Index.cshtml:

```
@model HtmlString

@Model
```

Solution 2, implement this in your Controller, a view is not needed:

```
public HtmlString Index()
{
    return new HtmlString("<p>Hello World!</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx):

```
return Content(String.Format("<p>Date: {0}</p>",DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: i actually create .cshtml files programmatically. For example i gonna use @Html.TextBoxFor(...) or foreach statement in my string.

Answer (score 0):

RazorEngine solves my problem exactly. Thanks everybody.
http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: How did you use it in your case? I'm having similar issues.. Thanks!